# creating an ID using calculated value

Tags: custom-list, calculated-column

I have 2 content types which I want an individual ID(unique for each item) for both, how would I go about creating an ID's for this. So each Content type has IDs 1,2,3,... etc.
I am thinking the way forward is using calculated values, but not sure how to go about this. Can anyone help?

Comment: [This(http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97841/list-item-with-specific-id-value) can be a similar issue, talking about ID. But you still cannot have 2 similar ID.

Comment: This is separate from the list ID, it is an ID within the content type I want to create.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the ID, so I think you should create a new column (or more). But since you cannot see the ID among the available values in calculated column, you have to use a workflow. In the workflow you can then create a value for your column(s) based on ID and on content type used.